# Python : Float object no iterable

Tags: python, recursion

I have to calculate a equation  that have a recursion. But if I am execute the code i get the failure that the Float object is not iterable

my code is:

```
def v(t, c):
    result = []
    if t == 0 or c == 0:
        return 0
    q = v(t - 1, c) - v(t - 1, c - 1)

    return max((0.2*(400-q)), (0.6*(400-q)), (1*(1200-q)), (0.85*(1115-q)), (0.87*(1127-q))) + v(t-1,c)
```

x = v(2, 1)
print(x)

What can I do to get the result? Thank you

Comment: `max` takes an iterable, you pass it a `float`. The error message is quite to the point. What do you want the maximum of there when  you pass a single value to the function?

Comment: can you post error message here ?/

Comment: Max should be passed a tuple. Float given

Answer (score 0):

You are using max(), but args in your function is a tuple (0.85 * (1115 - q)) + (0.87 * (1127 - q)), this is not right

Comment: in reality my code is:

 return max((0.2*(400-q)), (0.6*(400-q)), (1*(1200-q)), (0.85*(1115-q)), (0.87*(1127-q))) + v(t-1,c)

i delete a part of the code to make it easier to understand

Answer (score 0):

`max()` needs to be passed more than one argument and in your case only one argument is there which is causing the error. Try removing `max` or add one more results to your `max()` function to make it behave correctly.

```
def v(t, c):
    result = []
    if t == 0 or c == 0:
        return 0
    q = v(t - 1, c) - v(t - 1, c - 1)
    return ((0.85 * (1115 - q)) + (0.87 * (1127 - q))) + v(t - 1, c)

x = v(2, 1)
print(x)
```

Comment: in reality my code is:

 return max((0.2*(400-q)), (0.6*(400-q)), (1*(1200-q)), (0.85*(1115-q)), (0.87*(1127-q))) + v(t-1,c)

i delete a part of the code to make it easier to understand

Comment: it is running fine then ? i have checked it by running online and it is giving 1200 as an answer !!

Comment: @SerkanKılınç please accept and upvote answer if it solved your problem